# SequelizeConnectionError PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I am new to Sequelize and I am stuck at this error which I am not able to replicate in my local. The local works just perfect with the same db credentials but is giving a code `PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST` when its deployed.
Here's the connection string:

```
  CONFIG.DB,
  CONFIG.DB_USER,
  CONFIG.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: CONFIG.DB_HOST,
    port: CONFIG.DB_PORT,
    dialect: CONFIG.DB_DIALECT,
    define: {
      freezeTableName: true,
    },
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
    operatorsAliases: 0,
  }
);
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
    {
      "message": "Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "filtered_employee_records"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "name": "SequelizeConnectionError",
          "parent": {
            "fatal": true,
            "code": "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST"
          },
          "original": {
            "fatal": true,
            "code": "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST"
          },
          "stacktrace": [
            "SequelizeConnectionError: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
            "    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)",
            "    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)",
            "    at async /home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32",
            "    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)",
            "    at async /home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:301:26",
            "    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:407:12)",
            "    at async Function.findAll (/home/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1134:21)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Any idea on why it could be happening and how to tackle this? TYIA